# Is it possible to find random documents in collection, without same fields? (monogdb\node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example, I have a collection `users` with the following structure:

```
{
   _id: 1, 
   name: "John",
   from: "Amsterdam"
},
{
    _id: 2,
    name: "John",
    from: "Boston"
},
{
    _id: 3,
    name: "Mia",
    from: "Paris"
},
{
    _id: 4,
    name: "Kate",
    from: "London"
},
{
    _id: 5,
    name: "Kate",
    from: "Moscow"
}
```

How can I get 3 random documents in which names will not be repeated?

Using the function `getFourNumbers(1, 5)`, I get array with 3 non-repeating numbers and search by _id

```
var random_nums = getThreeNumbersnumbers(1, 5); // [2,3,1]
users.find({_id: {$in: random_nums}, function (err, data) {...} //[John, Mia, John]
```

But it can consist two Johns or two Kates, what is unwanted behavior. How can I get three random documents ( `[John, Mia, Kate]`. Not `[John, Kate, Kate]` or `[John, Mia, John]`) with 1 or maximum 2 queries? Kate or John (duplicated names) should be random, but should not be repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go - see the comments in the code for further explanation of what the stages do:

```
users.aggregate(
[
    { // eliminate duplicates based on "name" field and keep track of first document of each group
       $group: {
            "_id": "$name",
            "doc": { $first: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        // restore the original document structure
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$doc"
        }
    },
    {
        // select 3 random documents from the result
        $sample: {
            size:3
        }
    }
])
```

As always with the aggrgation framework you can run the query with more or less stages added in order to see the transformations step by step.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the `$group` aggregator, which will give you the distinct value of the collection. It can be used as:

```
db.users.aggregate( [ { $group : { name : "$name" } } ] );
```

**MongoDB docs:** [Retrieve Distinct Values](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#retrieve-distinct-values)